# Can desktop app desktop-bridged via Visual Studio call UWP APIs?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

I'm a bit confused about calling [Calling UWP APIs from a desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/uwp-apis-callable-from-a-classic-desktop-app). The last sentence of the first paragraph of this link states:

```
a WPF, Windows Forms, or Win32 app cannot call UWP API unless the app is packaged in an MSIX package.
```

Using `VS2019` I have `desktop-bridged` my WPF app (developed in `VS2019`). This process created a folder (under `...\AppPackages` folder) whose contents are shown below. Double clicking the `.appxbundle` from this folder, I can successfully  sideload the app on my `Windows 10` (and it gives me the option to upload to upload/publish to `Microsoft Store` as well):

**Question**: After satisfying some other requirement, can this app now call `UWP APIs`? As noted from the above link, the app needs to be packaged in an MSIX package. And I don't see any `MSIX` file in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is no important difference between an APPX and an MSIX package, or whether you have packaged your application using the desktop bridge, a `Windows Application Packaging project` or manually using `MakeAppx.exe`.

The package file extension is `.msix` (or `.msixbundle` if you are creating a [bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/bundle-msix-packages)) if the target version is set to 1809/October 2018 Update/Build 17763/RS5 or later. Otherwise it's `.appx`.

Both APPX and MSIX packages are installed and can be used the exact same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can call UWP APIs from a desktop bridge app whether it is packaged as APPX or MSIX.

> Therefore, if an API requires a package identity, a WPF, Windows
>   Forms, or Win32 app cannot call it unless the app is packaged in an
>   MSIX package.

I guess by **packaged in an MSIX package** they mean **packaged either in an MSIX or an APPX package**. They just did not mention APPX because MSIX is the new format.

However, be aware that some of UWP APIs, mostly UI related ones, can only get called from a real UWP app and not from a packaged Win32 or Wpf app.

Comment: This is not true anymore since the 1903 update. Now all UWP APIs can be used thanks to XAML Island. At least thats what MS is telling us. Testing is on my Agenda but not done so far other then reading and compiling the samples. But it seems to be a great step forward.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Thank you for sharing your thoughts and clarifying the possible confusion about `….MSIX or an APPX package...`.

Comment: @Lothar I think the `1903 update` extends the `XAML Hosting APIs` for desktop apps - and not necessarily all UWP APIs for desktop apps - at least not yet.