# Targeting windows versions in uwp apps

Tags: uwp, windowsversion

I have a desktop app which is converted to UWP app using MSIX packaging tool.
I need to support all version of windows so I have manually updated the TargetDeviceFamily MinVersion and MaxVersionTested in manifest file. But when I am uploading the msix package to Windows store I am getting the error :

**You cannot upload msix/msixbundle/msixupload packages that targets Windows MinVersion <= 10.0.17134.0.**

Below is the code that I have modified.

"I have installed Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10240 and 10.0.18362.1 on my system.
Also I am referencing few dlls for accessing windows apis. I have manually referenced the dlls as suggested in this link targeting sdk version 10.0.18362.0.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance

```
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.10240.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.18335.0" />
  </Dependencies>
```

**How do I support all version of windows for my UWP app(Converted using MSIX Packaging tool) ?**

**Version installed on my system : 10.0.17763**

Comment: MSIX Packaging is not supported on earlier versions of Windows 10. You should use a separate appx package for earlier versions or use a single appx package for all versions of Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSIX was officially introduced with version 1809 of Windows 10, and Microsoft then added support for it to the April 2018 Update (version 1803) and the October 2017 Fall Creators Update (version 1709).

It's not supported on earlier versions. Please refer to the support matrix in the [offical docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/msix-1709-and-1803-support).

You may create an APPX package for earlier versions. There is no crucial difference between an APPX and an MSIX package really:  [Can desktop app desktop-bridged via Visual Studio call UWP APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066165/can-desktop-app-desktop-bridged-via-visual-studio-call-uwp-apis/57077267)

Comment: Thanks...Now I am using Advanced Installer to support other version of windows as well.